# Only the original thread that created

Tags: android

I don't understand the meaning of Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy. Please can someone help me to solve this problem.

Thank you
................................

```
This is my class

public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {
    UserFunctions userFunctions;
    Button btnLogout;
    ListView mainListView;
    SessionManager session;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;  
    public static String name;
    public static String email;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
            session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
            btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_logout);
            mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.listView_groups_prof);  

            new Connection().execute();     
    }

      private class Connection extends AsyncTask {

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
                connect();
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                //connect();
            } 


      }

      private String  connect() {

          if(session.isLoggedIn()){
          HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();            
          String idv = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID).toString();            
          String typev = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_TYPE).toString();

          try {
              URL url;
            String myurl= "http://trouvermoi.com/android_login_api/src/controller/GroupeProfesseurController.php?tag=getgroupesprofesseur&idp="+idv;
              System.out.println("URL : " + myurl);

            url = new URL(myurl);

              HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              connection.connect();
              InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

              String data = InputStreamOperations.InputStreamToString(inputStream);          

             System.out.println("data :      " + data);
              JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
              JSONArray empInfo = jsonObj.getJSONArray("emp_info");
              final String[] values = new String[empInfo.length()];
              ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 1);                
              for(int i = 0; i < empInfo.length(); i++){
                  JSONObject obj = empInfo.getJSONObject(i);
                  String groupe = obj.getString("groupe");
                  String professeur = obj.getString("professeur");
                  values[i]=groupe;
              }
              mainListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , values));
              mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), values[position].toString(),
                       //   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                       //When clicked evrywhere, open prologue.java
                      Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, Elevespargroupe.class);
                        intent.putExtra("id",values[position].toString());
                        startActivity(intent);
                }
              });


            } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

          btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                session.logoutUser();
                Intent in =  new Intent(DashboardActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
            }
        });

     }else{
        Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(login);
      }

          return null;

        }

}
```

And this is my LogCat

```
02-06 11:33:28.795: I/System.out(2358): data :      {"emp_info":[{"id":"1","groupe":"1","professeur":"1"},{"id":"2","groupe":"2","professeur":"1"}]}
02-06 11:33:28.805: W/System.err(2358): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
02-06 11:33:28.815: W/System.err(2358):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
02-06 11:33:28.815: W/System.err(2358):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:854)
02-06 11:33:28.815: W/System.err(2358):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4077)
02-06 11:33:28.815: W/System.err(2358):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10379)
02-06 11:33:28.815: W/System.err(2358):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10334)
02-06 11:33:28.825: W/System.err(2358):     at android.widget.AbsListView.resetList(AbsListView.java:1840)
02-06 11:33:28.825: W/System.err(2358):     at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:504)
02-06 11:33:28.825: W/System.err(2358):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:444)
02-06 11:33:28.825: W/System.err(2358):     at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.DashboardActivity.connect(DashboardActivity.java:103)
02-06 11:33:28.835: W/System.err(2358):     at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.DashboardActivity.access$0(DashboardActivity.java:71)
02-06 11:33:28.835: W/System.err(2358):     at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.DashboardActivity$Connection.doInBackground(DashboardActivity.java:60)
02-06 11:33:28.835: W/System.err(2358):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-06 11:33:28.846: W/System.err(2358):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-06 11:33:28.846: W/System.err(2358):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-06 11:33:28.855: W/System.err(2358):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-06 11:33:28.855: W/System.err(2358):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-06 11:33:28.865: W/System.err(2358):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Asked bazillion times ... do not touch UI elements from non UI thread ... so network operation(and parsing) should be in `doInBackground` and creation of Adapter and ListView setup in `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accesing views in different thread call Activity's method runOnUIThread()

Change your connect method to the one below:

```
private String  connect() {

        if(session.isLoggedIn()){
            HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
            String idv = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID).toString();
            String typev = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_TYPE).toString();

            try {
                URL url;
                String myurl= "http://trouvermoi.com/android_login_api/src/controller/GroupeProfesseurController.php?tag=getgroupesprofesseur&idp="+idv;
                System.out.println("URL : " + myurl);

                url = new URL(myurl);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                String data = InputStreamOperations.InputStreamToString(inputStream);

                System.out.println("data :      " + data);
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray empInfo = jsonObj.getJSONArray("emp_info");
                final String[] values = new String[empInfo.length()];
                ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 1);
                for(int i = 0; i < empInfo.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject obj = empInfo.getJSONObject(i);
                    String groupe = obj.getString("groupe");
                    String professeur = obj.getString("professeur");
                    values[i]=groupe;
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mainListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , values));
                        mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text

                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), values[position].toString(),
                                //   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                //When clicked evrywhere, open prologue.java
                                Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, Elevespargroupe.class);
                                intent.putExtra("id",values[position].toString());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            session.logoutUser();
                            Intent in =  new Intent(DashboardActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(in);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });



        }else{
            Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(login);
        }

        return null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the adapter in your doInBackground method of AsyncTask which run on non UI thread that is background thread so you cant touch UI components from non UI thread.

To handle this do your UI work in onPostExecute of AsyncTask which will automatically be called after doInBackground finishes it work